# TypeError: map[msg[1]] is not a function

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I've been coding a simple chat bot. As I tried to switch over from switch statements to map arrays, I was greeted with this error: TypeError: map[msg[1]] is not a function

I would like to know what's causing this error, and how to fix it.

An example of the code:

```
function simpleReactSearch(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv) {
    if (priv > 0) {
        var map = {
            "hooray": heyListen(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv),
            "hellowound": helloWound(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv)
        }
        map[msg[0]]();
    }
}

function heyListen(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv) {
    var map = {
        "hi": commonReact("greeting", handle, priv),
        "hello": commonReact("greeting", handle, priv)
    }
    map[msg[1]](); //The line of the error.
}

function helloWound(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv){return;}

function commonReact(react, handle, priv) {
    switch(react) {
        case "greeting":
            return("Hi there, "+handle+"!");
        case "morning":
            return("Blah blah blah, "+handle+"!");
    }
}
var msg = new Array(),
pureMsg = new Array();
msg[0] = "hooray";
msg[1] = "hi";
pureMsg[0] = "hooray";
pureMsg[1] = "hi";
var reaction = simpleReactSearch("Wound",msg,pureMsg,2);
if (reaction !== null) {
    alert(reaction);
}
```

Yet something like this works just fine:

```
function func1(){alert("func1");}
function func2(){alert("func2");}
function func3(){alert("func3");}

var msg = new Array();
msg[0] = "hooray";
msg[1] = "hi";

var map = {
    "hi": func1,
    "hello": func1,
    "test": func2,
    "whatever": func3
}

if(msg[0] === "hooray") {
    map[msg[1]]();
} else {
    alert("failure");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var map = {
>     "hooray": heyListen(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv),
>     "hellowound": helloWound(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv)
> }
> ```

Here you're already calling the functions, and assigning their results (`undefined` values) to the `map` slots. When you try to execute those, you're getting the error that they're no functions.

Instead, assign the function objects themselves, and pass the parameters only when you're calling them:

```
var map = {
    "hooray": heyListen,
    "hellowound": helloWound
}
map[msg[0]](handle, msg, pureMsg, priv);
```

Same goes for the `heyListen` code.

Comment: Functions can also return functions. I use that technique a lot when I need a programmatic way to build a callback. I also use that technique when using partial applications and binding. Underscore's bind and partial are perfect for this.

Comment: Or set the values to functions: `hooray: function(){ return heyListen(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv); }`

Comment: @Sukima: Sure, but *in here* they're not returning functions ;-) And I guess the OP didn't want to use closures here.

Comment: @Bergi So it was to do with this all along! I was planning on returning the function, but it turns out I don't have any need to, I can code it another way. Thanks!